# Specifiying the possibles extensions to upload in a asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multipartform-data

i have done an asp.net mvc application for uploading file: 
i have this View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading_validation", "Akeo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="dossier" />
   <br />
    @Html.Label("Date d'expiration")

    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="duree" />
    <br />
 <input type="submit" value="OK" />
 }
```

I'd like to choose only the compressed files( .zip .iso .rar) .

So how can i make them  the only possibles extensions to upload and also to display only these extension when i browse the files?

Comment: Browsers do not expose a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While if you want to validate it on server you can do it using the code below

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    if (extension != null && extension.ToLower() != ".xlsx")
    {
       return "please upload file with extension .xlsx";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it on client side to check extension using jquery, go to the link to get the codes

[jquery - Check for file extension before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852090/jquery-check-for-file-extension-before-uploading)

Comment: Please put a warning on that to do validation client AND server side!